# Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in RDD.class refers to term hadoop in package org.apache which is not available

Tags: apache-spark

> Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in RDD.class refers
>   to term hadoop in package org.apache which is not available. It may be
>   completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the
>   classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling
>   RDD.class.
>
> Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading
>   class file 'RDD.class'. Could not access term io in value
>   org.apache.hadoop, because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check
>   your build definition for missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run
>   with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.) A full
>   rebuild may help if 'RDD.class' was compiled against an incompatible
>   version of org.apache.hadoop.
>
> Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading
>   class file 'PairRDDFunctions.class'. Could not access term io in value
>   org.apache.hadoop, because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check
>   your build definition for missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run
>   with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.) A full
>   rebuild may help if 'PairRDDFunctions.class' was compiled against an
>   incompatible version of org.apache.hadoop.

Comment: You really should provide additional information about what it is you are trying to achieve, and at what point you get the error. Just posting a bunch of error messages will not get you much further.

Comment: I try wordcount use scala with IDEA  but when make JAR get error  I have add  spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.8.4-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.8.4.jar   any lib need add?

Answer (score 1):

I have already solved now ,  add hadoop jars can solve